# Static constexpr array of class objects inside the class itself

Tags: c++, arrays, static, constexpr

Is it possible to have something like this in C++:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) {}

    static constexpr Foo table[] =
    {
        Foo(0),
        Foo(1),
        Foo(2),
    };
};
```

I have tried several combination, but none work. It works if table is not part of Foo class, however I would really like it to be part of the Foo namespace.

---

**Edit:**

The reason I want this is so I can access the table as `Foo::table`. I have several classes like this in a namespace and it is really convenient if I can import the class I am using by writing `using someNamespace::Foo` and then access the table as `Foo::table`. If the table is outside the class I have to always access it by writing `someNamespace::fooTable`.

Comment: @tobi303 No, because table is static.

Comment: ups sorry overlooked that

Comment: It can't work because when the `table` is parsed you don't have the full definition of `Foo`. To create an instance of `Foo` you need the full definition, the compiler must have parsed the whole structure until the end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, the compiler error explains is well enough. I guess there is no way to achieve something like this. I also edited the question to explain why I would like something like this in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [compiler error is clear here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sIvEivUIbvnnkEFR):

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Foo'
         Foo(0),
              ^
note: definition of 'struct Foo' is not complete until the closing brace
 struct Foo
        ^~~
```

`Foo` is considered an ["incomplete type"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) until the closing brace of its definition is reached. The size of incomplete types is not known, so the compiler doesn't know how much space `table` would require.

---

Here's a workaround:

```
struct FooTable
{
    constexpr auto operator[](int n) const;
};  

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) {}

    constexpr static FooTable table{};
};

constexpr auto FooTable::operator[](int n) const
{
    constexpr Foo table[] =
    {
        Foo(0),
        Foo(1),
        Foo(2),
    };

    return table[n];
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rb3ZtylSitOmR9t0)

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = Foo::table[1];
}
```

If you don't want `Foo` to be copied, you can place `table` inside a "detail" `namespace` and then return `const auto&` from `FooTable::operator[]` - [example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fANc9r6YlVKaJqc8).

Comment: The question is how can I achieve something like this, not why it does not work. The compiler error is descriptive enough to understand why.

Comment: Cool workaround :) However it does not have the desired functionality. The operator[] returns a copy, which for a compile time table is not really desirable. I have added some code to your [**live example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/huHhOZyOj3c8Nsh1) to show this.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the last wandbox example only compiles because of guaranteed copy elision in C++1z. It fails in C++14. The array initializer must be adjusted to not use copy initialization.

Comment: @StoryTeller [**Here is a C++14**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gXC4GLjT7ZYYAz9S) working version.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following trick, which basically moves the table to a templated wrapper, which is instantiated only when the class definition of `Foo` is complete.

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    static constexpr T table[] = { T(0), T(1), T(2) };
};

struct Foo : public Wrapper<Foo>
{
    int x;
    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

Not sure whether this is actually an acceptable workaround in your situation, but it is how you can get your example to compile and [run](http://cpp.sh/76e7d).

If you want to specify the initialization values of your table entries within the `Foo` class, you can extend the wrapper to take those values:

```
template<typename T, int... Args>
struct Wrapper
{
    static constexpr T table[] = { T(Args)... };
};

struct Foo : public Wrapper<Foo, 0, 1, 2>
{
    int x;
    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

In both cases you can have all your classes derive from `Wrapper` without the need to define additional ones, since the statics of `Wrapper` exist per instantiation. If you need your entries to take values other than `int`, you can also pass that type as another template argument:

```
template<typename T, typename A, A... Args>
struct Wrapper
{
    static constexpr T table[] = { T(Args)... };
};

struct Foo : public Wrapper<Foo, int, 0, 1, 2>
{
    int x;
    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
};

struct Bar : public Wrapper<Bar, char, 'a', 'b', 'c'>
{
    char x;
    constexpr Bar(char x) : x(x) {}
};
```

Passing multiple arguments to each constructor is achievable as well. Use a `std::pair` or some other wrapper to group them in that case.